# jQuery Or PHP (How Would I Do This) must wait 8 seconds before submit

Tags: php, jquery

I have 2 buttons.

Button A: A button.
Button B: Submit button.

What I am trying to do is, when user clicks on button A, it will send him a link.
But he won't be able to submit using button B until 8 seconds has passed since when he clicked on button A.

I am not to sure if its possible to do with PHP, is it?
If not, how would I do this with jQuery?

Maybe set a date on click using jQuery like var futureTime = time+8sec. if (!futureTime) { echo this }

Comment: some javascript can enforce it at the client end, IN THAT WINDOW/TAB. but the user can simply extract the link and use it in another window and bypass the restriction completely, so you MUST also enforce it on the server.

Comment: you can disable the button B when the button one is clicked  and after x amount of time re enable it.. you can use jquery and css to implement this eg:     $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");

Comment: and if user  disables js ?

Comment: @Dagon In this case we don't really care, most of users won't do this because they won't really know. The thing is, it's a voting system and we do not have a callback for this toplist, therefore we can atleast put timers, but I am not to sure how would I do this with PHP. if not, javascript..

Comment: it depends of the sensibility of the data, probably javascript will do the trick, but if you consider this behaviour a business rule, you should mix it up with php

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$("button#a").click(function(){
   $("button#b").prop('disabled', true);
   setTimeout(function(){ 
        $("button#b").prop('disabled', false); 
   }, 8000);
});
```

If by sending a link you mean "open a new page", then you can add just this to your load script on the page being open:

```
   $("button#b").prop('disabled', true);
   setTimeout(function(){ 
         $("button#b").prop('disabled', false); 
   }, 8000);
```

Comment: What if I want to send the user an error if he clicked on submit before 8 seconds has passed?

Comment: Then you can't use the "disabled" and need to handle the click event with a different logic: button#a --> set some bool to false --> click#B --> if bool is false show error, else submit

Comment: Can you show an example please? I have just tried doing this, and the JS says that my var is not defined, but if I define it default as false, js will overwrite the true to false?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you should check the form using PHP, as JavaScript can be turned off. Especially when dealing with sensitive data, people will try to pass the JavaScript part.

Here's an idea you can you use to check the time the user took to send in the form. If it comes "too early" you can create an error, otherwise you can execute your logic. You should combine this with a JavaScript part like [fmsf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16429138/1456376) suggested, to avoid massive sending of the form.

**PHP**

```
// start the session to store the current time and a key
session_start();

// check if the key exists in the session and was the send with the form
if (isset($_SESSION['key']) &&
    isset($_POST['key']) &&
    $_SESSION['key'] == $_POST['key']) {

    // if the difference to "now" is more than 8 seconds include your logic
    if (8 < time() - $_SESSION['timestamp']) {
        // your logic
    } else {
        // create an error message
    }
}

// create a new key and store it together with the current timestamp
$key = uniqid('', true);
$_SESSION['key'] = $key;
$_SESSION['timestamp'] = time();
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <!-- include the key in a hidden field in the form -->
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php print $key; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="value" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```